# PostgreSQL pgAgent

Tags: windows, postgresql, centos, pgadmin, pgagent

I am having trouble setting up pgAgent on my machine. I have a remote CentOS server wherein my PostgreSQL database was installed. I have already executed the pgagent.sql script and was able to create jobs and schedules using sql script. However, the schedule was fixed at 1 minute interval based on the pgagent.sql script. I want to have multiple jobs with different schedules. I cannot seem to find the Jobs icon in my pgAdmin (I am using Windows and am remotely connecting to my PostgreSQL DB which resides in a CentOS server)[image]

Comment: Which version of PG is your server running?

Comment: I am currently using pgAdmin 1.18.1 on my Windows Machine and the PostgreSQL that I am currently running is PostgresPlus 9.3AS

Comment: Then you should not run the pgagent.sql script but instead download and install the pgagent extension.